# if any specific request fails in the jmeter performance test with lots of users then what should we do to improve its performance?

Tags: jmeter

i am running a script, in the script 2 specific requests are failing when i am increasing number of threads and in that case, make them pass i have to increase my ramp up period.

for now i am taking no. of threads: 300
and ramp up period is: 1500sec
and its all good, passing it all requests.

but if i take less no. of ramp up period then its failing.

is it good to take this much of ramp up period or how can i improve those requests so it can pass?

what should be the good ramp up time here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of having [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) is increasing the load **gradually**. There is no "good" or "bad" ramp-up, any period is "good" once it's there.

In case of ideal application when you increase the load the throughput (number of requests per second) will increase proportionally and response time will remain the same.

In reality at some point response time will start increasing and the throughput will stop growing or even will go down. It's known as the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html).

Normally there should be non-functional requirements like the system should support X users with response time not more than Y. Or the system should support X requests per second.

If you're facing the issue when concurrency is high it indicates the system under test [bottleneck](https://www.educative.io/blog/performance-testing-101-bottlenecks) and there is nothing you can "fix" from JMeter side as increasing ramp-up period will decrease concurrency and mask the issue.

Comment: thank you. so what is the ideal number for throughput time and deviation. throughput should be high but how much and deviation should be low but how much?

Comment: Ideal number for throughput is [9223372036854775807](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE). Ideal deviation is 0. For "how much" refer to your [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) or common sense. Check out [Performance Metrics for Websites](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) and [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for more information on what do these metrics mean

Comment: if any specific request fails in the jmeter performance test with lots of users then what should we do to improve its performance? shall we consider that there is some performance issue in those specific request and we should improve them, if yes then what should need to improve?